# What's the difference between Nyquist rate and Nyquist frequency?

Tags: signals, signal-processing, nyquist

I have a homework question that asks for the Nyquist rate AND the Nyquist frequency of a signal. I thought the two were synonymous?
I tried to read their definitions but it just looks like the same thing worded differently.

Answer (score 1):

The Nyquist rate is the minimal frequency at which you can sample a signal without any undersampling. It's double the highest frequency in your *continous-time* signal.

Whereas the Nyquist frequency is half of the sampling rate. You'll notice that your amplitude graph from 0 Fs to 0.5 Fs is the mirror image of 0.5 Fs to 1 Fs. The Nyquist frequency represents that folding point.

Comment: To relate the two: The highest frequency of the continuous-time signal *is* the Nyquist Frequency. So half of the Nyquist Rate is the Nyquist Frequency.